# How to do runtime polymorphism using Arc<Mutex<dyn SomeTrait>> in Rust?

Tags: rust

Suppose I want to write a code that on runtime can receive different types of decoder that share the same interface, that is `trait Decoder`. I'd like to get the `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>` and downcast to my specific decoder. Something like this:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait Decoder {}

struct SpecificDecoder1;
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder1 {}

struct SpecificDecoder2;
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder2 {}

fn main() {
    let decoder: Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(SpecificDecoder1));

    if let Ok(specific_decoder_1) = decoder.downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder1>>() {
    } else if let Ok(specific_decoder_2) = decoder.downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder2>>() {
    } else {
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db1078aa701b60f9bae57730031e89a2)

Errors:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast` found for struct `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:26:45
   |
26 |     if let Ok(specific_decoder_1) = decoder.downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder1>>() {
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>`

error[E0599]: no method named `downcast` found for struct `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:28:52
   |
28 |     } else if let Ok(specific_decoder_2) = decoder.downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder2>>() {
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>`
```

But `downcast` has this implementation only:

```
pub fn downcast<T>(self) -> Result<Arc<T>, Arc<dyn Any + 'static + Send + Sync>>
```

where
T: Any + Send + Sync + 'static,

it looks like `T` has to implement `Any`. I guess I have to do something like this:

```
impl Any for SpecificDecoder1 {
    fn type_id(&self) -> TypeId {
       //what to do here? TypeId has no constructors
    }
}
```

Also, is this the right way? On C++ I'd use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<SpecificDecoder1>` and etc. This is what I want to do.

Comment: Do you get an error if you omit the `impl Any for SpecificDecoder1` declaration? It is provided automatically.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes, I forgot to add, please look at https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db1078aa701b60f9bae57730031e89a2

Comment: Mutexes need to be locked before you access the inner data, so that applies here too when downcasting. The error there has nothing to do with `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you assume an inheritance relation between `Arc<dyn Decoder>` (or `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>`) and `Arc<dyn Any>`. I do not think that this assumption is correct - trait objects do not inherit. The following lines work:

```
fn main() {
    let decoder: Arc<dyn Any + Send + Sync> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(SpecificDecoder1));

    if let Ok(specific_decoder_1) = decoder.clone().downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder1>>() {
        println!("specific 1");
    } else if let Ok(specific_decoder_2) = decoder.clone().downcast::<Mutex<SpecificDecoder2>>() {
        println!("specific 2");
    } else {
        println!("else");
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't I be able to downcast from `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>` to `Arc<Mutex<SpecificDecoder1>>`? I don't expect inheritance, it's that `SpecificDecoder1` and `SpecificDecoder2` share the same trait, so `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>` should be ok to downcast to both. Letting a function accept `Arc<dyn Any>` is error prone, it can accept anything, not just `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>`, that's why it's important.

Comment: Look at the definition of [downcast](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.downcast). It expects `self` to be `dyn Any`. And `dyn Any` contains only the methods of `Any` and not the type information of `Mutex<dyn Decoder>` left. Let us wait whether someone else knows a trick.

Comment: @CoronA: `trait Decoder {` -> `trait Decoder: Any {` will do it, but you'll need `Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>`

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=770e83cf3206cdc76505e06e60b57b68 Couldn't make it work

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You need to downcast the `&dyn Decoder`, not the `Mutex` containing it. You can't downcast that.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I don't get it. `Arc`'s `downcast` method only downcasts to what the `Arc` holds. Could you give an example?

Comment: You need to lock the mutex, then downcast what the mutex holds. You can't downcast the Mutex itself, since you can't even look at the mutex contents (to find if the type matches) without locking it.

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible to downcast from a `Arc<Mutex<dyn Trait>>` into a `Arc<Mutex<Type>>` though you'll see below it requires some `unsafe` and its not a great workflow. I would encourage exploring other avenues before this (and general disclaimer that **downcasting is often a code-smell** indicating poorly defined abstractions).

Anyway, one crucial part is that casts from `Arc<A>` to `Arc<B>` *are* possible if `A` and `B` are compatible - meaning they have the same size, alignment, and fit other criteria as if doing a [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) (and same `Drop` behavior is ideal though not technically required). If those criteria satisfied, then this cast is done via `Arc::into_raw` and [`Arc::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.from_raw) with a pointer cast in between. See documentation on the latter to know more.

We also know that transmuting from `Mutex<dyn Trait>` to `Mutex<Type>` is *safe* (if `dyn Trait` is `Type`) because [unsized coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#unsized-coercions) necessitate they have the same layout.

The other crucial part: we need to extend from the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait since it provides a `type_id()` method to get the current type when behind a `dyn Decoder`.

With those together, we can do the downcast like this:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait Decoder: Any {}

struct SpecificDecoder1;
struct SpecificDecoder2;

impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder1 {}
impl Decoder for SpecificDecoder2 {}

fn downcast<T: Decoder>(decoder: &Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>) -> Option<Arc<Mutex<T>>> {
    if (*decoder.lock().unwrap()).type_id() == TypeId::of::<T>() {
        let raw: *const Mutex<dyn Decoder> = Arc::into_raw(decoder.clone());
        let raw: *const Mutex<T> = raw.cast();
        
        // SAFETY: This is safe because the pointer orignally came from an Arc
        // with the same size and alignment since we've checked (via Any) that
        // the object within is the type being casted to.
        Some(unsafe { Arc::from_raw(raw) })
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    let decoder: Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(SpecificDecoder1));

    if let Some(_specific_decoder_1) = downcast::<SpecificDecoder1>(&decoder) {
        println!("decoder1")
    } else if let Some(_specific_decoder_2) = downcast::<SpecificDecoder2>(&decoder) {
        println!("decoder2")
    } else {
        println!("neither")
    }
}
```

```
decoder1
```

This is still not ideal since you have to access the `Mutex` to see what it contains, but this is more of a demonstration of what is possible than anything.