# Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>> to Rc<RefCell<ConcreteType>>: What are the reasons it is not done in the std crate and how can we about doing it?

Tags: rust

How to go from `Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>>` to `Rc<RefCell<ConcreteType>>` ?

From the [rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#1313) there is **NO**

```
impl Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>> { 
    fn downcast<T: Any>(self) -> Rc<RefCell<ConcreteType>> { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

for the `cell` family with `dyn Any`.

There is however

```
impl Rc<dyn Any> { ... }
```

as seen from the [rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#1313).

- Is this use case intentionally left out by the rust std crate ? If so why (what limitations were faced) ? How can we get around this ?
- This equally applies to all forms of `std::cell` like:

  - `Rc<Cell<dyn Any>> TO Rc<Cell<ConcreteType>>`
  - `Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>> TO Rc<Cell<ConcreteType>>`
  - `Rc<OnceCell<dyn Any>> TO Rc<OnceCell<ConcreteType>>`

Is this because there is no provision in rust to detect that there can be multiple owners where one can point to a trait object while the other pointing to a concrete type for the same trait object: The `cell` controlling the interior mutability is unable to guarantee the rust borrow rules between the trait object and the corresponding concrete object ? If this is the reason is this not a limitation of the rust type system and the core language implementation ? I get that the concrete type has been erased to `dyn Any`, but still there must be a way to establish down-casting with interior mutability turned on.

Comment: While you use different types you should be able to apply the same pattern of checking and casting the pointer as in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115898/442760) to the linked duplicate, just replace usage of `Mutex` with `RefCell` and usage of `Arc` with `Rc`, since you already have a `dyn Any` you can omit the other trait and the `type_id` method.

Comment: As to why it's not in the standard library, probably because you'd have to do it for every combination of `SmartPointer<InteriorMutabilityType<T>>` and that's just a lot of extra implementations, `N x M`.

Comment: @cafce25 But why is this not done in the rust std library ? marking this as duplicate when there are still few unanswered questions seems a bit enforcing.

Comment: @cafce25 agree to disagree there as the question is directed towards the design of the rust std library and design choice made for it: it is within the bounds of practical implementation. The combination-al aspect called out by you sounds a reasonable justification for the question at hand but not a practical justification to prematurely close this question.

Comment: [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio) The way I interpret this, meta thinks the same way as I do. You're still free to disagree though.

Comment: A bit of the premise is wrong: to do downcasting through `Any` you must have access to the underlying instance. This is a problem for `OnceCell` since there may not be an inner value at all and its a problem for `Cell` since you must *move* out the inner value to access it, but `dyn Any` is `!Sized`. A `Rc<RefCell<dyn Any>>` is really the only practical variant, but still not very useful and the only currently possible implementation would have caveats (like having to "unlock" the inner value to do the conversion which may not be expected).

Comment: There are other problems like such conversion having limited utility over just accessing the inner `&dyn Any` and using the `.downcast()` method already there. And it doesn't compose well since this would only be a special case for `RefCell<dyn Any>` and not any adjacent variants. You could try creating a feature request on the rust-lang issue tracker to get more perspective there but I would guess it'd be rejected.